# How do I know when the binding is setting the textbox vs the user?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a form with a text box on it.  I create a BindingSource object, connect my DomainObject to it, then bind the BindingSource to a TextBox.  The code looks similar to this:

```
private BindingSource bndSource = new BindingSource();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bndProposal.DataSource = new DomainObject() { ClientCode = "123", EdiCode = "456" }; 
    txtAgencyClientCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bndProposal, "ClientCode", 
                                false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);

}

private void txtAgencyClientCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("txtAgencyClientCode_TextChanged");
}

public class DomainObject
{
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string EdiCode { get; set; }
}
```

The code works fine.  However, I'd like to know the reason the TextChanged event fires: is it because it is being set by the BindingSource or is it because the user entered something (or pasted it).  How do I get that information?

I've tried having a flag that's set when bindings are created, but at the time of the binding, the textbox is on a tab control that's not visible.  The event actually fires when I switch to the tab with the textbox in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the event after the text is set. Disable it in the designer and add it in the form load :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    txtAgencyClientCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bndProposal, "ClientCode", 
                                false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);
    txtAgencyClientCode.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtAgencyClientCode_TextChanged);

}
```

You can unsubscribe before each programmatic text modification if you want to be sure:

```
txtAgencyClientCode.TextChanged  -= txtAgencyClientCode_TextChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you have to use the `TextChanged` event for user entry?  Could you look into using another event instead, like `KeyPress`?  It all depends on what you need to do when the text changes.  The other option would be comparing the value on TextChanged with the DataBoundItem.